# How to get Doc2Vec to run faster with a CPU count of 40?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I am building my own vocabulary to measure document similarity. I also attached the log of the run.

```
tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=word_tokenize(_d.lower()), tags=[str(i)]) for i, _d in enumerate(data)]

max_epochs = 1000
vec_size =50
alpha = 0.025

tic = time.perf_counter()
#Building a model from the tokenized data

model = Doc2Vec(vector_size=vec_size,
                alpha=alpha, 
                min_alpha=0.0025,
                min_count=5,
                workers =5,
                dm =1)
  
model.build_vocab(tagged_data)


model.train(tagged_data,total_examples=model.corpus_count,epochs=max_epochs)



model.save("d2v.model")
print("Model Saved")

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"Time {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
```

[Log of Doc2Vec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5jFF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally due to threading-contention inherent to both the Python 'Global Interpreter Lock' ('GIL'), and the default Gensim master-reader-thread, many-worker-thread approach, the training can't keep all cores mostly-busy with separate threads, once you get past about 8-16 cores.

If you can accept that the only `tag` for each text will be its ordinal number in the corpus, the alternate `corpus_file` method of specifying the training-data allow arbitrarily many threads to each open their own readers into the (whitespace-token-delimited) plain-text corpus file, achieving much higher core utilization when you have 16+ cores/workers.

See the Gensim docs for the `corpus_file` parameter:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html#gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec

Note though there are some [unsolved bugs](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2757) that hint this mode might mishandle or miss training data at some segmentation boundaries. (This may not be significant in large training data.)

Otherwise, other tweaks to parameters that help `Word2Vec`/`Doc2Vec` training run faster may be worth trying, such as altered `window`, `vector_size`, `negative` values. (Though note that counterintuitively, when the bottleneck is thread-contention in Gensim's default corpus-iterable mode, some values in these parameters that normally require more computation and thus imply slower training manage to mainly soak up previously-idle contention time, and thus are comparitively 'free'. So when suffering contention, trying more-expensive values for `window`/`negative`/`vector_size` may become more practical.)

Generally, a higher `min_count` (discarding more rare words), or a more-aggressive (smaller) `sample` value (discarding more of the overrepresented high-frequency words), can also reduce the amount of raw training happening and thus finish training faster, with minimal effect on quality. (Sometimes, more-aggressive `sample` values manage to *both* speed training & improve results on downstream evaluations, by letting the model spend relatively more time on rarer words that are still important downstream.)